# Content height 100% producing vertical scrollbar

Tags: css

I've found a lot of questions asking something similar to this, but none of the solutions I've found have applied exactly to the problem I'm facing.

Basically, I've got a menubar, and then content, but I want the content's background colour to fill the height of the page. When I apply `height: 100%;` though, I get a scrollbar. I've read up about margin collapse, and it might be something to do with that, but no matter how many margins I get rid of and replace with mere `position: absolute;`, I can't get to the bottom of the situation.

Relevant bits of CSS are here:

```
body, html {
color: #000000;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:12pt;
background:#f2f2f2;
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

#menubar {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
background:#FDBB30;
height:80px;
width:100%;
font-weight:bold;
}

#content {
position:absolute;
top:80px;
width:92%;
left:50px;
background:#ffffff;
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use calc in css:

```
#content {
height:calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ydyonjw9/1/

Comment: This is a great help. There is still a scrollbar on the bottom, though, which I hadn't noticed before...

Answer (score 2):

```
#content {
position:absolute;
padding-top:80px; // instead of top:80px;
    box-sizing: border-box; // This will make your padding fit inside your height
width:92%;
left:50px;
background:#ffffff;
height:100%;
}
```

Here is working example of your question:

http://jsfiddle.net/t3xbL8dm/2/